# NotFoundHttpException error on post method Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I got error `NotFoundHttpException` below

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXTV3.png)

Here is my **route**

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('/contact', 'TicketsController@create');
Route::post('/contact', 'TicketsController@store');
Route::get('/tickets', 'TicketsController@index');
Route::get('/ticket/{slug}', 'TicketsController@show');
Route::get('/ticket/{slug}/edit', 'TicketsController@edit');
Route::post('/ticket/{slug}/edit', 'TicketsController@update');
```

My **function update** on TicketController

```
public function update($slug, TicketFormRequest $request)
{
    $ticket = Ticket::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
    $ticket->title = $request->get('title');
    $ticket->content = $request->get('content');
    if($request->get('status') != null) {
        $ticket->status = 0; } else {
    $ticket->status = 1;
}
$ticket->save();
return redirect(action('TicketsController@edit', $ticket->slug))->with('status', 'The ticket '.$slug.' has been updated!');

}
```

My **function edit**

```
 public function edit($slug)
{
    $ticket = Ticket::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
    return view('tickets.edit', compact('ticket'));
}
```

Am I missed something? I think my routes was right, maybe my update function is wrong

Comment: Why do you set the slug parameter as optional?

Comment: remove the question mark from the /{slug?}, it shouldn't be optional since both methods use it. Also, can you show us the html where this routes used and ensure the method is post

Comment: Also, `TicketFormRequest  $request`, which is being being injected into `update()`, should go before `$slug`.

Comment: Also, it can come from a route placement problem, like having Route with /ticket/profile and /ticket/{slug}. I have forgotten the order to place the routes, but you can rotate their positions(i.e. putting one above the order) to deduce which will work.

Comment: Idk exactly why. I just follow tutorial. I already try to remove questions mark and it doesn't work too for me @wadleo

Comment: Then checkout my last suggestion

Comment: I've tried to rotate route position. But it still doesn't work for mee @wadleo

Comment: then edit your answer with the full routes file and html, so we can help you better

Comment: I've edited all my routes @wadleo

Comment: show us the form where you call the place the route for updating the tickets

Comment: I can't add my code to stack overflow. So pls open on repo on github [link] (https://github.com/icungse/Learn-Laravel-5.1/blob/SupportTicketSystem/resources/views/tickets/edit.blade.php) @wadleo

Comment: okay, looking at that github file, the form doesn't have an action attribute, so it submits to  the current navigation url of the user

Comment: @Saiful have you found the issue

Comment: also, I will recommend you rename the last route to  
                                                                 Route::post('/ticket/{slug}/update', 'TicketsController@update');